# нажатие по правой части Button

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть Button, на котором я разместил drawable. Как мне чуть сдвинуть глаз влево, чтобы он был более удобным для нажатия? Как фиксировать, когда пользователь зажимает палец в том месте?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него

Answer (score 0):

Для пароля можно использовать стандартные виджеты из Material Design:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="30sp"
            android:labelFor="@id/second_input"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:textColorHint="#333333"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/first_input"
            app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
            app:passwordToggleTint="#333333">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_t"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:labelFor="@id/password_t"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:minHeight="48dp"
                android:textColor="#333333"
                android:textColorHint="#333333" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

это пример, но суть я думаю вы понять сможете, вам нужна строка:

```
app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
```

которая включает "глаз". Вот есть [хорошая статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/308318/) по данному вопросу.

P.S. Когда возникают вопросы такого рода, очень желательно добавлять разметку, а не просто скрин.

Comment: глаз уже работает? Или нужно прописывать в Java файле?

Comment: он работает из коробки, просто его нужно включить и всё.

Comment: как включить ? Прописать в xml?

Comment: да это разметка в активности/фрагменте где вы это поле хотите сделать, там таким образом можно использовать возможности библиотеки